# Disable uniqueness/fk constraints before django's loaddata for Postgresql 9.6/10

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to migrate data from one db to another. Previous was on peewee ORM and new one on Django. I've ported schema code and successfully run `dumpdata`. Now I need to run `loaddata` to restore from it.

Problem is that DB is pretty bad, there's a lot of uniqueness/fk violationss there for legacy reasons, and I don't really want to clean it before restore. I would like to be able to just disable all checks for some time and upload as is.

I tried `ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` but from the info on the Internet I think it only disables FK checks. Unfortunately I keep receiving IntegrityError's with uniqueness violations.

How can I disable uniqueness check temporarily on Postgres? Or all at once, if possible. Thanks.

Postgres 9.6/10, Django 1.11.9.